# Prevent overscroll/overflow in Skeleton UI Modal component

Tags: html, css, svelte, skeleton-ui

I am using the [Modal](https://www.skeleton.dev/utilities/modals) from Skeleton UI in my Mobile application, it works great except for one thing, every time the modal is opened it briefly displays a scroll bar and it makes it look kinda odd. I've tryied several things such as applying `overflow-none` everyiwhere that seemed relevant.

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: I have the same problem but it doesn't look too good because the official Skeleton site has it too :/ https://www.skeleton.dev/utilities/modals